# Python: Sorting array returns unintuitive order

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, zip

I have the two inputs and my output

```
Sorted_Array = ['Historic Rate', 'Overnight', '1M', '3M', '6M', '1Y', '2Y', '3Y', '4Y', '5Y', '6Y', '7Y', '8Y', '9Y', '10Y', '12Y', '15Y']

Input = ['6M', '2Y', '7Y', '1Y']

Output = ['7Y', '1Y', '6M', '2Y']
```

the output is unintuitive, it should be

```
Actual_Output = ['6M','1Y','2Y','7Y']
```

the code I use is:

```
Ouput = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(Sorted_Array,Input), key=lambda pair: pair[0])]
print(Output)
```

Can anyone see where this has gone wrong?

Comment: Why would you expect that output? I think your code is working properly....

Comment: you are sorting your sorted list, not using it to sort the the second list

Comment: Have you looked at what `zip(Sorted_Array,Input)` looks like ? The output is what one would expect. I don't know what you're trying to do but obviously you're doing it wrong ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently pairing the items of `Input` with the 4 first items of `Sorted_Array`:

```
>>> temp = list(zip(Sorted_Array, Input)))
[('Historic Rate', '6M'), ('Overnight', '2Y'), ('1M', '7Y'), ('3M', '1Y')]
```

Then you sort with a lambda function based on the first items of these tuples. Which is in the following order:

```
>>> sorted(temp, key=lambda pair: pair[0])
[('1M', '7Y'), ('3M', '1Y'), ('Historic Rate', '6M'), ('Overnight', '2Y')]
```

It should now be clear how you end up with the result you have. To sort based on the order of the elements in `Sorted_Array` can  the [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) function:

```
>>> sorted(Input, key=lambda item: Sorted_Array.index(item))
['6M', '1Y', '2Y', '7Y']
```

Note: the index function raises an exception if the item is not present in the list.

Comment: you mean raises a ValueError if there is no such item present in the list.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise I was doing this

Answer (score 0):

in python 2.x:

```
def dist(x,y):
     return sorted_array.index(x) - sorted_array.index(y)

output = sorted(input, cmp=dist)
```

In python 3.x:

```
def func(input):
    output = input
    for i in range(len(output)):
         try:
            output[i] = sorted_array.index(output[i])
         except Exception as e:
            output[i] = len(sorted_array)+1
    return output

output = [ x for x,y in sorted((input,func(input),key = lambda k: k[1])]
```

this should work

Comment: the sorted-array containing the order you are following to sort

Comment: You mean what the OP called `Sorted_Array`?

Comment: yes it is the Sorted_array of OP. i ll change it for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

`sorted(zip(Sorted_Array,Input), key=lambda pair: pair[0])` sort the result based on the key, the first member of the pair, from which you extracted the second member

```
>>>> Output = [x for x in sorted(zip(Sorted_Array,Input), key=lambda pair: pair[0])]
>>>> print(Output)
[('1M', '7Y'), ('3M', '1Y'), ('Historic Rate', '6M'), ('Overnight', '2Y')]
>>>> Output = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(Sorted_Array,Input), key=lambda pair: pair[0])]
>>>> print(Output)
['7Y', '1Y', '6M', '2Y']
```

you need to change the key to `pair[1]`

```
>>>> Output = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(Sorted_Array,Input), key=lambda pair: pair[1])]
>>>> print(Output)
['1Y', '2Y', '6M', '7Y']
```

Comment: That's not the expected output, the OP says it should be `['6M','1Y','2Y','7Y']`.

Comment: well, i'd say the OP expected it to be intuitive, which I'd argue sorted by the actual first char 1, 2, 6 7 is more intuitive than using the 2nd char M, Y, Y, Y. But my actual intention is to pointed out the usage of `key=lamda pair: pair[0]` there (in line with his question: Can anyone see where this has gone wrong?).